# Attach in-memory database in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I created in-memory database in Android. I put **null** in **name** parameter in SQLiteOpenHelper constructor:

```
SQLiteOpenHelper(context, null, null, 1);
```

Also I created some *doc_orders_products* table in the in-memory db.

Now I'm trying attach this in-memory db to my main on-disk db. 
What name of in-memory db should I use in ATTACH command?

I tried:

```
mainDB.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE ':memory:' AS temp_db");
```

and

```
mainDB.execSQL("ATTACH DATABASE '' AS temp_db");
```

Both ATTACH command performs well even when in-memory db isn't created at all.
But when I try get access to tables in the in-memory db, they are not present. I get exception. E.g.:

```
10-11 14:07:46.782: E/AndroidRuntime(2107): Caused by: 
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: 
temp_db.doc_orders_products (code 1): , while compiling: 
INSERT INTO temp_db.doc_orders_products SELECT * FROM 
main.doc_orders_products WHERE doc_id=3
```

Is it possible to attach in-memory db to on-disk db? What correct way is to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason you cant initialize it 'on disk'?

Comment: I want to increase performance. I hope in-memory database works faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every new connection to an in-memory database creates a new, empty database.
So your `ATTACH` commands attached to a *different* database.

What you should do is to use the `ATTACH` command and then create your tables, through the `mainDB` connection, in the `temp_db` database; e.g. `CREATE TABLE temp_db.doc_orders_products(...`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try. As I understand in-memory database will be removed from memory when I DETACH it. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, `DETACH` closes the connection.

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct syntax is

```
ATTACH DATABASE 'file::memory:' AS temp_db;
```

Example:

```
sqlite> attach DATABASE 'file::memory:' AS temp_db;
sqlite> create table temp_db.t1 (_id integer);
sqlite> create table t1 (_id integer);
sqlite> insert into temp_db.t1 values(1);
sqlite> insert into t1 values(2);
sqlite> select temp.*, t1.* from temp_db.t1 as temp, t1;
1|2
```